# Behavior of printf on passing less arguments in it

Tags: c, printf

I have just noticed a different behavior of printf function by changing the no. of arguments and the format specifiers. Please take a look on the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ int ji=65;
  printf("ji>=65 ? %d : %c",ji);
 }
```

The output comes out to be **ji>=65 ? 65 : A**
**The character printed is A**
But if the code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ int ji=65,y;
  printf("ji>=65 ? %d : %c",ji);
  printf("%d",y)
}
```

The character printed in this case is **heart(ascii value 3)** and the value of **y** is **12803**.

How the character value is being picked up by the compiler??? Please help

Comment: It is undefined behavior, anything can happen; just random memory.

Comment: Oh, no more "plox explain this UB" questions, OK? Don't expect us to make sense of the nonsense.

Comment: @H2CO3 The behaviour is absolutely explainable by implementation details. So it's not making sense of nonsense. For me it looked like aman wants to find out something about the mechanics behind this undefined behaviour. In my opinion it's not a question of what the standard says, it's more a question of "how things work". Comparable to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523637/cant-understand-the-output-of-the-simple-c-code-about-function-call-in-linux

Comment: Upvoted because this is a legitimate question about the low level workings of printf.

Answer (score 10):

The call to `printf()` in the posted code results in undefined behaviour:

```
printf("ji>=65 ? %d : %c",ji); /* One less argument than required for
                                  the supplied format. */
```

From section *7.19.6.1 The fprintf function* of the C99 standard:

> The fprintf function writes output to the stream pointed to by stream, under control of the string pointed to by format that specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. **If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.** If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored. The fprintf function returns when the end of the format string is encountered.

This behaviour also applies to the `printf()` function (and the `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` function).

Answer (score 0):

It's taken from the stack. You are telling printf that it can fetch 2 arguments from the stack but you only provide 1 argument. Printf doesn't know about this and takes the next value on the stack which is most likely the value of a register saved during invocation of printf.

But note: The value you get is always undefined.

Comment: The C standard doesn't specify that arguments have to be passed in a particular way - in particular, I know that `printf` in x86-64 variants of Linux has a "how many arguments are in `xmm` registers as an extra argument specifically for `printf` (style) functions.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks for the hint. But this does not explain the result he is getting. In fact I'm more used to embedded implementations of printf where the cause is what I wrote above. Wasn't aware of the x86-64 implementation. Just out of curiosity: Isn't that behavior a question of the ABI of the platform?

Comment: My point is that the C standard doesn't say `printf` has to be fetching it's arguments from any particular place - just "if you pass this in, it should output that" [but with many more words than that...]. How arguments are passed to `printf` is entirely up to the ABI, yes.

Comment: @junix : Sir the character printed in the first code is equivalent to the ascii value 65 which is stored in ji, but in the second code when we add an extra line in code it shows an abnormal behavior. Also if, according to u it picks up the value from stack then, **it should have picked up the garbage value of y as it will be on the top of the stack** ( i guess, i'm not sure of it)???? **Also, the character printed is different while the garbage value of y is different. why???** can u please explain???

Comment: @aman: Nobody cares why it prints different garbage. The program is badly formed and it's a waste of time to try to reason about what it should or should not output. Fix the bug and carry on.

Comment: @aman It depends on the stackframe and is hard to tell what really is interpret as second parameter. I'm pretty sure it's not `y` which is next to the parameter `ji` on the stack because printf has for example a return value, but it's all speculation. Because of the complexity to predict the behavior it's called "undefined". That's where Blastfurnace' answer comes in.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of arguments passed to `printf` is fewer than the number of conversion specifiers in the format string, or if the types of the arguments aren't correct for the corresponding conversion specifier, then the behavior is *undefined*, meaning pretty much any result is possible (and considered "correct").  *How* that result is obtained will vary from situation to situation.

If the number of arguments passed to `printf` is greater than the number of conversion specifiers, then the additional arguments are evaluated but otherwise ignored.

Note that block-scope variables like `y` are not implicitly initialized to any particular value; their value is *indeterminate* and may even be a trap value, so you shouldn't expect any particular output for the second `printf` statement.

Also, unless your compiler documentation *explicitly* lists it as a valid signature, `void main()` will also lead to undefined behavior.  Use `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: when **y** is not printed why the character corresponding to ascii value 65 is only printed( which in this case is stored in ji and even mentioned in the first printf statement)???? **Is this an undefined behavior or it is because of the argument passed ji???**

Comment: @aman: It's because the behavior is undefined.  Once you invoke undefined behavior in the first `printf` statement, the behavior of the program as a whole becomes undefined.  "Undefined" simply means that the compiler is not required to handle the erroneous code in any particular manner; it can choose to issue a diagnostic and halt translation, or it can ignore the problem and plow ahead, generating erroneous machine code, or anything in between.  If you're *really* curious you can look at the generated machine code, but it won't necessarily tell you *why* you got that result.

Comment: Theoretically, the compiler could execute rm -rf /* and still be in compliance with the standard

Comment: @Demetri: Theoretically, yes, but the odds of any compiler vendor doing that are pretty low for what are hopefully *obvious* reasons (although I remember hearing stories about one compiler that launched "Rogue" when it encountered undefined behavior).  More likely, you'll just get garbage output, incorrect behavior, or a segfault.

Comment: @John Bode 9 I know - any compiler that did this on purpose would probably be illegal (as in law) malware! I was just trying to make a point. The compiler you mentioned was early versions of GCC on encountering a #pragma directive, which they did not constructively support and which has implementation-defined behavior.